# Where do you get GPS tracks (hikes) for southeast Asia?

Tags: hiking, gps

I'm trying to find websites providing GPS tracks for southeast Asia.

I'm mostly interested in hiking but other activities would also be interesting.

So far I only bumped into 2 interesting websites: [wikiloc.com](http://wikiloc.com) and [bikemap.net](http://bikemap.net).

Note that the map feature in wikiloc is pretty cool to find nearby GPS traces [wikiloc.com/wikiloc/map.do](http://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/map.do)

Answer (score 2):

Garmin Basecamp is a free application that allows people to share tracks for various activities. I have found a ton of trails this way.

http://adventures.garmin.com/

Comment: Nice one. Have you found trails for southeast Asia though?

Comment: @AdrienBe no, because I haven't searched for Asia, but feel free to download it and take a look, I bet there are some.

Comment: This link redirects me to the main Garmin page without any "adventures".